# Smooth vs regular vs non-singular

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a very basic question, but I can't find a clean answer anywhere.

In introductory algebraic geometry books working over the complex numbers, it's usual to use these three words interchangeably.  A point on a variety $X$ is smooth/regular/nonsingular if the dimension of the tangent space at the point is equal to the dimension of the variety.

On the other hand, I know that people sometimes find it important to distinguish between these terms, maybe when defining smoothness of morphisms, or working over non-closed fields,...

I want to make sure I know the right definitions of these terms in current use.  In what contexts should each be defined?  What implies what?  How should I think of them?

Edit: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_scheme , which says there are regular schemes that aren't smooth.  There are also these notes of Vakil, where he has crossed out "smooth" and replaced it with "nonsingular": https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class21.pdf  The notes seem to suggest it's because "smooth" is reserved as a property of morphisms.  Is there a reason Wiki is happy to say "smooth scheme" but Ravi isn't?  Is "nonsingular" the same as "regular"?

Comment: Have you considered searching in some books or internet. I did not see any case where these are used in different meanings

Comment: I clarified the question.  That page appears to use them interchangeably, which as the examples I've added show is not always done.  I am trying to understand the distinction.

Comment: I tend to use the terms interchangeably when describing a variety and when working over a base field (especially an algebraically closed field). But given a map of varieties $f:X\to Y$ over such a field, the map $f$ is smooth, or "$X$ is smooth over $Y$", means something much stronger than simply that $X$ is a non-singular variety. It means that every fiber of $f$ is non-singular. (This isn't the technical definition of smooth morphism, but it conveys what's going on in this setting.)

Comment: For a variety over an algebraically closed field, all 3 are equivalent. For schemes, I would avoid the classical term "nonsingular", which seems ambigous. Smooth implies regular in general; it is equivalent to "geometrically regular".

Comment: Further comments: (1) very roughly, you can think of a smooth morphism as an analogue of submersion in differential geometry (i.e. the differential is everywhere surjective). This is the condition ensuring that the fibers are subvarieties. For example $x \mapsto x^2$ is not smooth because the differential at 0 vanishes (corresponding precisely to the fiber above 0 being singular). More generally, a morphism between non-singular curves over alg. closed field is smooth if and only if it is unramified.

Comment: (2) Smoothness is related to number theory: an extension $L/K$ of number fields is everywhere unramified if and only if $\mathrm{Spec} \mathcal{O}_L \to \mathrm{Spec} \mathcal{O}_K$ is smooth.

Comment: Here is the page on Stacks Project summarizing smoothness of ring maps; items 12-15 compares it with regular ring https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TZ

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the general context, "regular" is a property of a scheme (or a ring, or local ring), and "smooth" is a property of a morphism of schemes.

"Regular" means exactly that at every point, the dimension of the (Zariski) tangent space is equal to the (Krull) dimension (of the local ring at that point).

A map $f: X \to Y$ is smooth if the fibers over geometric points of $Y$ are regular, and $f$ is locally of finite presentation and flat.

We also use the relative point of view, so a scheme $X$ over $S$ is a smooth scheme over $S$ if the map $X \to S$ is smooth.

The first potential source of confusion is that a map between two regular schemes can fail to be smooth. This is not hard to see once you realize that there's no need for the fibers to be regular - for instance $xy$ defines a map $\mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb A^1$.

The second potential source of confusion is that a regular scheme over a perfect field is necessarily smooth over that field, but for an imperfect field this fails. See [some examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrically_regular_ring). Usually over an imperfect field you want to consider smooth schemes and not regular ones as they are better-behaved.

Going in the other direction, smooth schemes over non-regular bases can fail to be regular, but smooth schemes over regular bases will be regular.

I think people rarely use "nonsingular" when they are trying to be careful about this distinction, but I think it's more likely to mean "regular".

Comment: Thank you good sir.

Comment: @Bort Indeed, thanks.

Comment: A third important difference: When one says that a ring $R$ is smooth, one generally means that $R$ is smooth over some subfield $k$ which is clear from context. But a ring can be regular without containing ANY subfield, like the ring of integers.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer That's a good point, although a scheme can also be smooth without lying over any subfield, like a smooth scheme over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Right, although I think most algebraic geometers are unlikely to say "smooth" when they mean "smooth over $\mathbb{Z}$". To me, my comment is the main response to "why define regular at all"? The situation with imperfect fields suggests that regular is a worse behaved notion than smooth. But what is good about regularity is that I can say that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(xy-p)$ is regular, whereas it is not smooth in any useful sense.